# [Microsoft]"wmic" connect to a computer that is out of domain?

Tags: domain, remote, local

[microsoft]
i try to "**wmic**" inside a computer to **get** it **back** **inside** the **domain** (getting desynced). the **problem** is that when i do it from my **administration user**, the wmic **request** getting **denied** as the computer (as mentioned above) is **out** **of** my **domain**.
**how** do i send the **request** **from** the remote computer (**target**) **local** **admin** name?

i can do it via MSTSC, but i like to use wmic instead for script abilities.

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Any reason why you bolded seemingly random words in your question? This doesn't help with readability.

Answer (score 1):

Invoke WMIC with the `/USER` and `/PASSWORD` options.
Due to the problem you describe, you need to provide a local account on that computer (not a domain user).